# how to update a python dictionary by using the keys of arbitrary length?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using python 2.4 to update a dictionary which is very complex and maybe unknown, and the keys is complex but explicit. for example, the dictionary is :

```
dict1 = {
  'server' : {
    'index' : 0,
    'info' : {
      'ip' : '127.0.0.1',
      'user' : {
        'number' : 1001,
        'tel' : '123456'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

now I want to update(delelte or modify) it by using the key 'server'-'info'-'user'-'number'.

I want to update a dictionary by using a explicit keys list while I only know the dictionary object except its internal data, what should I do?

Comment: Do you mean the value is complex? The key is just a string.

Comment: yes, the key is just a string, and I could split it by '-'.  and I only know the dictionary name.

Comment: Please describe an example of modifying

Comment: Is it always the same structure? I mean: dict1["server"]["info"]["user"]["number"] to access "number"?

Comment: yes, the structure is always the same.

Comment: modifying is : dict1["server"]["info"]["user"]["number"] = 1002.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider

```
>>> def get_nested(d, keys):
...     return reduce(dict.get, [d] + keys)
... 
>>> def set_nested(d, keys, value):
...     get_nested(d, keys[:-1])[keys[-1]] = value
... 
>>> dict1 = {
...   'server' : {
...     'index' : 0,
...     'info' : {
...       'ip' : '127.0.0.1',
...       'user' : {
...         'number' : 1001,
...         'tel' : '123456'
...       }
...     }
...   }
... }
>>> 
>>> keys = 'server-info-user-number'.split('-')
>>> get_nested(dict1, keys)
1001
>>> set_nested(dict1, keys, 2555)
>>> dict1
{'server': {'info': {'ip': '127.0.0.1', 'user': {'tel': '123456', 'number': 2555}}, 'index': 0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this to parse your key, `'server-info-user-number'`:

```
def get_from_dict(d, key):
    keys = key.split('-')
    for key in keys:
        d = d[key]
    return d 

def set_from_dict(d, key, val):
    keys = key.split('-')
    for key in keys[:-1]:
        d = d[key]
    d[keys[-1]] = val

dict1 = {
  'server' : {
    'index' : 0,
    'info' : {
      'ip' : '127.0.0.1',
      'user' : {
        'number' : 1001,
        'tel' : '123456'
      }
    }
  }
}

key = 'server-info-user-number'
print(get_from_dict(dict1, key))
set_from_dict(dict1, key, 1002)
print(get_from_dict(dict1, key))
```

(returns `1001` for the first get, then sets to `1002` and fetches that value.)